# What could be reason for - ANR :Input dispatching timed out

Tags: android, google-play, android-anr-dialog

When i am installing an application from google play getting

**ANR: Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting because no window has focus but there is a focused application that may eventually add a window when it finishes starting up.)`**

But when i install it locally form my machine, application works successfully.
Not sure what is the reason behind this and how to fix and verify.

Comment: Are you showing a dialog at the beginning. Also, while installing from your local machine are you completely uninstalling the application manually before doing so?

Comment: No not showing dialog, and uninstalling app before installing from local machine

Comment: What about my second question. Also, is your launch activity has a probable blocking code in `onCreate()` before calling `setContentView()`?

Comment: Seems like launch activity has a blocking code, will look into it once

Comment: did you resolved this issue ???

Comment: did you resolved this issue ???